# Opening PSD files with Fireworks groups all the elements

Tags: photoshop, cs4, fireworks

i'm trying to open a psd file with fireworks because i feel much comfortable using fireworks than photoshop, but my problem is that the layers are group in fireworks but when i open it with photoshop i can see different layers.can anyone please tell me what i must do to ungroup all the layers and be able to super select each layer on the design page?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's this got to do with programming?

Comment: Try asking this on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click on the layer and see there is a option saying ungroup.try this  :)